# javascript: collection[id][prop] = collection[id][prop] || [] //problems assigning a blank array to object

Tags: javascript

So I have a JSON object representing album information. Given "function updateRecords(id, prop, value)" I want to  be able to update each of the entries. The correct finished code is below.
I was given an instruction, bold part, I don't understand:

> If prop is "tracks" but the album doesn't have a "tracks" property,
>   **create an empty array before** adding the new value to the album's
>   corresponding property.

The solution is the line:

```
collection[id][prop] = collection[id][prop] || []
```

So I'm setting it equal to itself OR a blank array? I don't understand the logic there. The situation: I have a singular value I want to assign to an object property. But I want the value to be in an array, so I can assign more values to it later if necessary. Ok great I get that part. But why Can't I just say collection[id][prop] = [] if I want an array created...what's the 'or' for?

The full problem is from: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/record-collection

```
var collection = {
  2548: {
    album: "Slippery When Wet",
    artist: "Bon Jovi",
    tracks: [
      "Let It Rock",
      "You Give Love a Bad Name"
    ]
  },
  2468: {
    album: "1999",
    artist: "Prince",
    tracks: [
      "1999",
      "Little Red Corvette"
    ]
  },
  1245: {
    artist: "Robert Palmer",
    tracks: [ ]
  },
  5439: {
    album: "ABBA Gold"
  }
};


function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
  if(value === "") delete collection[id][prop];
  else if(prop === "tracks") {
    collection[id][prop] = collection[id][prop] || []; //This line here I don't understand 
    collection[id][prop].push(value);
  } else {
    collection[id][prop] = value;
  }

  return collection;
}
```

Comment: if `collection[id][prop]` is falsy, it will assign the new array instead. So it's a shorthand of first checking `if (!collection[id][prop]) { collection[id][prop] = [] }`

Comment: You can't just create a new array every time because you would overwrite / delete the other entries in `collection[id][prop]` if there is already something in that array. With the "OR - logic" you don't delete the entries if there is already sometihing included. Means in short: `collection[id][prop] ` is filled with `collection[id][prop] ` if something is already in that array. Otherwise it is filled with an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `||` operator returns the first *truthy* value from the operands given to it. If the  `collection[id][prop]` has an array object as its value then the array object would be treated as a *truthy* value and that value will be returned from the expression.

If the `collection[id][prop]` is `undefined` that is the absence of the array then it would treated as a *falsy* value and the second operand the blank array object would be assigned to the `collection[id][prop]` .

In the example snippet below see the `||` operator returns the blank array object as the first operand is `undefined` which would be treated as a *falsy* value:

```js
const val = undefined || [];
console.log(val);
```

The `||` is a short circuiting operator if the first operand is *truthy* it does not check the second operator it returns the first:

```js
const val = [1, 2, 3] || [];
console.log(val)
```